# R3 Corda role management system

Tags: user-roles, corda

Does R3 Corda have any built-in role management system that can allow filtering query results or access? This could be a mechanism built in connection with the API but it would help if there was a standardized way of handling this common requirement. This would be outside of the code used in the contract or flow code.

Comment: You could give a few examples of how you'd like to filter query results/control access?

Comment: This would be more fine-grained than permission of the node itself to view transactions. There are requests to provide an admin system to assign various specific privileges to users through roles. The privileges would determine, for example, which properties of a list of transaction states could be shown or not shown based on role privilege. This is common in the business world for role-based permissions.

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't exist currently. Permissions are only granted in terms of operations users can perform, and not in terms of the data they can retrieve.